# Extracting image dpi in Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3

Are there any tools or ways to extract DPI from image (gif, png) in ActionScript?

Answer (score 0):

Not all images contain DPI information... for example GIF's do not and some jpgs taken with a digital camera do not...  in general DPI is only useful to the printer and is useless for web based applications (unless you are creating an image to send to the printer)... you might download the evaluation version of NikkoImage which has DPI detection http://www.NikkosArt.com/NikkoImage and extract out the code to detect DPI...

Also google ImageInfo  * Based on java class, ImageInfo.java, by Marco Schmidt
   * (http://schmidt.devlib.org/image-info/)

Answer (score -1):

Your question makes no sense.

DPI (dots per inch) of an image displayed on a screen is equal to the DPI of that screen.

There are tools like Photoshop that let you set a DPI but that is because they work with both the size of the canvas and the resolution of the image and the DPI will be applied when you print that image.

Comment: Sorry I might be wrong. I thought DPI on computer screen makes no sense.